# Return JavaScript call from the controller of ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, error-handling, callback

I want to handle some errors in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. Earlier I was developing WebForms applications and I've used `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, but MVC != WebForms with its server controls, postbacks etc... So I'm a little bit confused.

Of course I can return from the Controller a JSON response using smth like `return Json(...)`, but wait.

I have a View. It has an exact markup. How does my View recognize which modalbox I must call from my jQuery + bootstap code?

**First of all, I thought to use GET parameters for handling query string.**

If /Index/UserNotExist -> Than call a jQuery function with showing custom modalbox

Else if other some URL -> Than call a jQuery function with showing the same modalbox, but with other text in it.

I've tried to use some code to handle current location, but failed (strange, that it the end of script block some jQuery's script are well running, but exact that script even wasn't firing).

**Then I thought about cookies, to write temp data in cookie and make a simple check.**

But in WebForms such a check in code `if (Request.Cookies["error"] != null` is running well, MVC doesn't even accept such a check it would always make exceptions.

I'm a little bit tired and want to listen to your suggestions.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to expose server side errors in your client? Sorry but I'm not following here what you need.

Comment: @RacielR. yes, you are correct, I need exactly error screening at client side with javascript getting results from the endpoint of controllers. But I thought, I have described my problem correctly for understanding :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I bring errors from the server to the client -when no using ajax to consume my controller's actions- is by using [TempData](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html#.UcnGcPn0XDE).

I usually have a base controller where I put this plus other plumbing that is common to all my controllers.

So, this method

```
    protected void AddError(string message, string header = null)
    {
        TempData[Constants.ErrorKey] = new ViewMessage
        {
            Type = eMessageType.Error,
            Header = header,
            Content = message
        };
    }
```

Adds the error message to TempData.

In my _Layout.cshtml I have a section to display errors, using bootstrap's alert:

```
@if (TempData[Constants.ErrorKey] != null)
{            
    var error = TempData[Constants.ErrorKey] as ViewMessage;
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <br />
        <h4 class="alert-heading">@error.Header:</h4>
        <p>@error.Content</p>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

So anytime calling an action in any controller produces a business logic error, there is an alert with the error content.

You can actually combine action filters for unhandled exceptions and be as sophisticated as you need, but this is the basic idea.

Off course you can also use the Session but TempData is more suitable because the values are disposed after you use them.

If, on the other hand, you are using ajax to interact with your actions, then it is pure client side scripting and dom manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetUser(int userId)
    {
        var user = // Get user by user id.
        if (user == null)
           return null;
        else
        {
           var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           return Json (new {user = serializer.Serialize(user)});
        }
    }
}

public class ModalViewController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string message)
    {
       ViewBag.Message = message;
       return PartialView("ModalView");
    }
}

var actionUrl = '/User/GetUser';
var data = { "userId": userId };

$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (user) {
           ShowModalView(user == null || user.length <= 0);
       },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")"));
    });

function ShowModalView(userExists) {
var actionUrl = '/ModalView/Index';
var data = { "message": userExists ? "hi there user" : "oops, no user found" };

$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (modalView) {
        $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(modalView);
       },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")"));
    });
}
```

So essentially, you first make an ajax call to the action method to check if user exists, and then make another ajax call to return a partial view of your modal view. The modal view gets the message from the ViewBag, and in the success callback method of your second ajax call, you can render the partial view, in the main view, wherever you want.

Comment: no, you didn't understand what I need, but although thanks for the attention

Comment: How about now? ShowModalView() will make another ajax call to the ModalViewController to show the view with the correct message.